# MPJ -Express error while using mpjboot

Tags: java, linux, mpj-express

I am trying to configure a linux cluster for MpJ-Express.
I have set the PATH and MPJ_HOME correctly.

When i run the command  **mpjboot machines**

I am getting the following message.

```
mpjboot machines
grep: :/home/actdir/mpj-v0_38/conf/wrapper.conf: No such file or directory
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at runtime.starter.PortScan.main(PortScan.java:42)
mpjboot found port  busy on head machine. There are two possibilities:
    (1) The daemon might already be running...
    (2) If the daemon is not running, then set a different port by modifying the wrapper.app.parameter.2 property in the :/home/actdir/mpj-v0_38/conf/wrapper.conf file

The machines file is supposed to contain host names. even if i change the host names 
and verify the port number usage Iam getting the same error.

Plese suggest me about the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `wrapper.conf` file is not accessible or available for `mpjboot`. The error above shows that it fails to get port number from `wrapper.conf` (no such file or directory erro). In `PortScan.java` information about the port number is missing thats why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.`
I would suggest you to check if your shared filesystem is working properly (NFS is working fine).In MPJ Express 0.38 release you need to have shared filesystem i.e. a single view of `$MPJ_HOME` directory is visible to all the nodes. 
If you still see this error you can enable debugging by following userguide and share logs on [mpjexpress mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mpjexpress-users)